# is the ASCII charset endian-safe?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii

I was doing the math, if I keep every bit of information ( the content of a variable ) in a binary representation ( binary file in binary mode ) always under or equal to 1 byte I'm safe no matter what endianess is being implemented on the platform, this means that an ASCII charset is endian-safe or bi-endian by definition since it offers 2^8 permutations ?
I suppose that UTF-8 is not bi-endian as consequence of this.

Comment: Endianness is not defined for one byte. And UTF-8 can be both little and big endian (just like any other Unicode encoding).

Comment: You are confused about what utf-8 is. An utf-8 encoded string is a sequence of bytes and is not affected by endianness. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: @H2CO3 **CAN** be, but my point is on the safety, if I have an ASCII character I can assume that the char is always reproduced correctly, with an UTF8 I should care about the implementation of that UTF charset .

Comment: @PascalCuoq any UTF8 implementations is more than just a charset, UTF8 also contains informations about the flow of the text, I'm not sure that the UTF8 is safe as any other implementation of the UTF8 standard, also the ASCII is just a table with glyph-char association, nothing really fancy, it's extremely simple.

Comment: @user2384250 What does “I'm not sure that the UTF8 is safe as any other implementation of the UTF8 standard” even mean? Anyway, braving any risk of repeating myself, an utf-8 encoded string is a sequence of bytes. Read the link I provided. The first sentence is “By early 1992 the search was on for a good byte-stream encoding of multi-byte character sets”. Guess how the story will end?

Comment: @H2CO3 UTF-8 can only be both little and bit-endian in the sense that endianness is meaningless for bytes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Endianness refers to byte order, that is, the order in which the bytes of a multibyte sequence appear.

For ASCII it is meaningless as there are no multibyte sequences.

For UTF-8, the UTF-8 standard already precisely and unambiguously defines the order of bytes in all of its multibyte sequences. There is so need for an extra rule (such as big-endian or little-endian) to specify or clarify this order. So... also not applicable.

Comment: so the UTF8 is safe no matter what ? and the UTF-16 ?

Comment: UTF-16 uses fixed-size (16 bits) multibyte code units, so the concept of endianness if applicable. Sadly, the Unicode consortium chose not to mandate one endianness or the other for the standard, so we are left with two "variants" of UTF-16. That is just one of the reasons why [UTF-16 should be avoided whenever possible](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/102205/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful).

Comment: The other main reason why it should be avoided is that it is a "worst of both worlds" encoding: it is a variable length encoding (unlike UTF-32/UCS-4, which you should use when you need fixed length code units) and ASCII-incompatible (unlike UTF-8, which you should use in pretty much every other case).